# What should I take into consideration when deciding how to pass callbacks to addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

What should I take into consideration when deciding how to pass callbacks to `addEventListener`, given the following approaches?

```
element.addEventListener('click', function(){
    // ...
});
```

or

```
function doSomething(){
    // ...
}
element.addEventListener('click', doSomething);
```

or

```
element.addEventListener('click', function doSomething(){
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Imho they have both their usecase, so this question might attract very opinion based answers. Sometimes it makes sense to use the one, sometimes the other. Mostly when you reuse the functionality in your event handler, it is more interesting to use a named function (no code duplication). But it really depends on your code and what framework you might be using behind the scenes

Comment: Using a named function is always preferred over using an anonymous function, especially for debugging as the named function is easily identified in the stack trace.

Comment: @Icepickle Could you maybe name some more use cases for each? I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: Since I can no longer answer the question...There are two things to consider: *Anonymous vs Named Functions* and *Reusability*. Anonymous functions are more concise, named functions are easier to debug, etc. If you want a function to be reusable, you'll have to declare it outside of the `addEventListener` function call, but if you're only using it once, you can declare it inside the `addEventListener` function call. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_function_expression_(function_expression))

Comment: Vote to reopen. I think we can already see an answer based on facts, references and specific expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code snippet uses an anonymous function. [Todd Motto has written an article](https://toddmotto.com/avoiding-anonymous-javascript-functions/) listing some reasons why you should avoid using anonymous functions in callback functions:

> - Are more difficult to debug
> - Cannot be reused
> - Cannot be tested easily
> - Do not describe the role of the function
> - Make code lack structure
> - Create messier/unclear code
> - Documentation will suffer (things like jsDoc)

Comment: Thank you. Seems like i will continue with named functions.

Comment: Thank you zxxz. Also adhering to these types of best practices can make commenting code unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

The first way is called an [anonymous function](http://helephant.com/2008/08/23/javascript-anonymous-functions/). I wouldn't really say there's a way you 'have to' or 'should' do it, but you'll usually see them used to create really simple one-off bits of logic that you don't want to bloat your code writing a new block for.

If you will need to debug your code, or you might want to reuse the code in the function, obviously your life will be better if you write a named function.